# Почему проверка не работает и получает stray '\361'?

Tags: c++, if

```
void f(char c)
{
if (с == '<')
    cout<<"WTF?";
return ;
}
```

Comment: нормально вопрос задайте, что не получается конкретно, что на вход подаете?

Comment: Передаю символ. Но при компиляции на этой строке пишет error: stray '\361' in programm

Comment: если вам помог ответ, пожалуйста, закрывайте вопрос, отмечая ответ как лучший

Answer (score 2):

У вас символ 'с' - кириллица, в if.
Для проверки нажмите ctrl+f и в строке поиска введите русскую 'с'.